# use mysqli_connect and mysql_select_db

Tags: php, mysql, database

This code works correctly!

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","laboratory");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

But when I remove database_name from mysqli_connect I would use the mysql_select_db, the following error occurs "Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in"

Code after change:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("laboratory", $con);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use laboratory : " . mysql_error());
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You cannot call mysql* functions on mysqli* resources. And it is not required as there is `mysqli_select_db`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't mix `mysqli` and `mysql` as they are different modules.

In your second code block you are using `mysql_select_db` and `mysql_error`, the first one requires `mysql` connection, not `mysqli` connection.

Comment: @Daniyal did you change $db_selected = mysql_select_db("laboratory", $con); to use mysqli equivalent instead?

Answer (score 4):

Replace Your Code:

`$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("laboratory", $con);` instead of

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("laboratory", $con);
```

Answer (score -1):

The order of the parameters has been changed from:

```
mysql_select_db($Database, $Connection);
```

to:

```
mysqli_select_db($Connection, $Database);
```