# mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters?

Tags: php, mysqli

First off the other questions that have been anwered don't help me. I still have the same problem so please don't mark this as a duplicate. Also I have to add data to my database.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vanille</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("realhtmlinphpfile.php"); 
mysqli_connect("localhost")
or die ("Fehler");

mysqli_select_db("test34")
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$Test1 = $_POST["Test1"]; 
$Test2 = $_POST["Test2"];
$Text3 = $_POST["Test3"]; 
$Test4 = $_POST["Test4"];

if($Test1 == "" or $Test2 == "" or $Test3 == "" or $Test4 == "") {
echo "FAIL";
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test34
(datum, autor, newstext)

VALUES 
('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```

Comment: Did you even try to lookup the php manual? http://php.net/mysqli_select_db

Comment: check this out.. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: What is your problem? If you suspect two params, did you try it?!

Comment: You could've found your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065282/use-mysqli-connect-and-mysql-select-db. Or in the php manual: http://php.net/mysqli_select_db

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_select_db()` requires 2 parameters :

1. The connection to the database (usually $link);
2. The database name

So for your connection your code should look like this :

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost") or die ("Fehler");

mysqli_select_db($link ,"test34") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich...");
```

You can check the doc of mysqli_select_db() for more infos :
http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 1):

You can connect Database mysqli as follow

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","my_db")  or die ("Fehler");
return $con;
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");
$sel = mysqli_select_db($con , "my_db")  or die ("Fehler");
return $sel;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the connection object as the first parameter:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
//    mysqli_connect("localhost);
mysqli_select_db($conn,"test34");
```

Answer (score -2):

The code looks really messy :-) You will need to save the handle from `mysql_connect()` to a variable and have this as the first parameter.

```
$c = mysqli_connect("localhost") or die ("Fehler");
mysqli_select_db($c, "test34");
```

PS: In my former answer I have mixed the parameters myself as I was referring to the older `mysql` functions.

Comment: You switched parameters. Its `mysqli_select_db($c, "test34");` according to http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: @Nidhoegger You are right, I have corrected the error.